# How do I build an expression to call an equality operator from a base class?

Tags: c#, linq

If the type in question implements `operator ==()`, then I can easily build an expression to call it. But if the operator is defined in the base class, it doesn't work - see how three of the assertions pass but one fails.

Is there a correct way to do this?

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(new A(42) == new A(42)); // PASS
        Assert.IsTrue(ExecuteOperatorEqual(new A(42), new A(42))); // PASS
        Assert.IsTrue(new B(42) == new B(42)); // PASS
        Assert.IsTrue(ExecuteOperatorEqual(new B(42), new B(42))); // FAIL
    }

    static bool ExecuteOperatorEqual<T>(T item1, T item2)
    {
        var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<bool>>(
            Expression.Equal(
                Expression.Constant(item1),
                Expression.Constant(item2)));
        return expression.Compile()();
    }
}

class A
{
    private readonly int _value;

    public A(int value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(A left, A right) => left._value == right._value;

    public static bool operator !=(A left, A right) => left._value != right._value;
}

class B : A
{
    public B(int value) : base(value)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" - in what way does it fail?

Comment: See the comments in code: the first 3 assertions pass, but the 4th does not.

Comment: Hmm, I guess [Expression.Equal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352749.aspx) does not look at the superclass when it tries to find the equality method. [This overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352235.aspx) allows you to specify a MethodInfo..

Comment: `((Expression<Func<bool>>)(() => new B(42) == new B(42)))` gives a `MethodBinaryExpression` pointing to `A.op_Equality`.

Comment: Note: An operator is not inherited (but overwritten). It is static and therefore statically bound. Each static method is completely independent and doesn't know anything about the existence of the other one, even if the argument types are related. Only the compiler knows both and chooses one of them according to the rules of overwriting..

Comment: Thanks @StefanSteinegger. Updated the title to try to express that idea a little better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it does make sense in your context, but you can fix that problem passing the MethodInfo to you `Expression.Equal`

```
    static bool ExecuteOperatorEqual<T>(T item1, T item2)
    {
        BindingFlags bindingAttr = BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy;
        var equalityMethod = typeof(T).GetMethod("op_Equality", bindingAttr, null, new Type[] { typeof(T), typeof(T) }, null);

        var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<bool>>(
            Expression.Equal(
                Expression.Constant(item1),
                Expression.Constant(item2),
                false,
                equalityMethod
                ));
        return expression.Compile()();
    }
```

I've had reflected `System.Core.dll` and the `Parameter` class does not search for any overloaded operator, as you can see below:

```
    private static MethodInfo GetUserDefinedBinaryOperator(ExpressionType binaryType, Type leftType, Type rightType, string name)
    {
        Type[] types = new Type[]
        {
            leftType,
            rightType
        };
        Type nonNullableType = leftType.GetNonNullableType();
        Type nonNullableType2 = rightType.GetNonNullableType();
        BindingFlags bindingAttr = BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
        MethodInfo methodInfo = nonNullableType.GetMethodValidated(name, bindingAttr, null, types, null);
        if (methodInfo == null && !TypeUtils.AreEquivalent(leftType, rightType))
        {
            methodInfo = nonNullableType2.GetMethodValidated(name, bindingAttr, null, types, null);
        }
        if (Expression.IsLiftingConditionalLogicalOperator(leftType, rightType, methodInfo, binaryType))
        {
            methodInfo = Expression.GetUserDefinedBinaryOperator(binaryType, nonNullableType, nonNullableType2, name);
        }
        return methodInfo;
    }
```

Adding the `BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy` would find the equality operator. They must have a reason to not add that to the `.Net`.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, in my context I don't know which type is implementing the equality operator.

Comment: I just added a code to find the equality method from the base class. Hope it can help you.

Comment: I think you don't need the line `var equal = typeof(B).GetMethod("op_Equality");`. Additionally, I would use binding flags, since operators are required to be public and static: `BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public`

Comment: In fact, only adding the BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy to the GetMethod invoking, finds the method in the inherited classes.

Comment: I tried `GetMethod(..., FlattenHierarchy)`. If two classes in the hierarchy define `op_Equality`, then it throws.

Comment: It doesn't throw an error if you pass the types expected in the method. `typeof(T).GetMethod("op_Equality", bindingAttr, null, new Type[] { typeof(T), typeof(T) }, null);`

Comment: That works, thanks! One important case is `struct`, which have value equality, even if they don't overload equality operators. For that I'm using `(dynamic) item1 == (dynamic) item2`